# How to make an element darker with a transition on hover?

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<div class="link" id="link1">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
</div>
<div class="link" id="link2">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
</div>
```

---

```
.link{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
    transition:0.25s;
}
.link:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
    transition:0.25s;
}
```

This makes the .link darker when you hover over it, but I'd love to hear if it's possible to add a transition to it.

EDIT: I should have made this clear in the first place. I have multiple links and I want all of them to transition to a darker version of their own color when you hover over it. I've updated the fiddle from before.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rpo12dhx/5/

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to transition to a darker color on `:hover`, you don't need `linear-gradient`. You could simply transition to a darker color.

Also, you did not specify the `transition-property`(i.e, `background`).

```css
.link {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #394053;
  transition: background 0.8s;
}
.link:hover {
  background: #172032;
}
```

```html
<div class="link" id="link1">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here's your fiddle updated

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rpo12dhx/1/)

took out the id selector and added the BG color to main selector, also don't think you can use :not psuedo on :hover pseudo done it as red to highlight the effect

```css
.link{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50%;
 float: left;
 transition:background-color 1s;
    -webkit-transition:background-color 1s;
     background-color: #394053;
}

.link:hover {
 background-color:red;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="link" id="link1">
 <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rpo12dhx/2/)

```css
.link {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
  transition: 0.25s;
  background: red;
}
.link:hover {
  background: darkred;
}
```

```html
<div class="link" id="link1">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
</div>
```

Note, the color can be any one you choose. (and can be sped up/slowed down by changing that `transition` value) - There is little need to include [vendor prefixes](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions) for this

**NB**

I see that all current answers have removed the `:not(hover)` part of your css. This is because of specificity. Think of it as "the more specific", the "more important".

So, The `.link` will be over written by the `.link:hover` when hovered because it is **more specific** than the plain ".link", and hence we do not need to include this.